# Delphi, MultiPartHttpDownloader from ICS: download several files sequentially

Tags: delphi

Can anybody tell me how to download several files sequentially using MultiPartHttpDownloader from ICS in Delphi?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sequentially?  One after another?

Comment: The TMultipartHttpDownloader loads _one_ file from http and uses MultiPart-download to accomplish that. Of course you can load more than one file "one after another". ICS is non-blocking! There is a TMultipartHttpDownloader-demo that comes with the ICS-Sourcecode.